# group by column and except one value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table : messages

```
id  is_main  message    status
-------------------------------
1    0        testt      1
2    5        testt2     1
3    4        testt3     1
4    5        testt4     1
5    0        testt5     1
6    5        testt6     1
7    4        testt7     1
8    5        testt8     1
9    0        testt9     1
```

i want to group by is_main but except is_main = 0

The result i want

```
id  is_main  message    status
-------------------------------
1    0        testt      1
2    5        testt2     1
3    4        testt3     1
3    0        testt5     1
4    0        testt9     1
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: i cant get all the is_main value is 0

Comment: Can you explain how the results are related to the inputs?  For instance, what is the logic for the `id` column?

Comment: select * messages where status=1 group by is_main

id  is_main  message    status
-------------------------------
1    0        testt              1
2    5        testt2            1
3    4        testt3            1

but i want

id  is_main  message    status
-------------------------------
1    0        testt               1
2    5        testt2             1
3    4        testt3             1
4    0        testt5     1
5    0        testt9     1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally group by using `CASE WHEN ... THEN`. First you group by `is_main` column, then you must add special random value column for records not equal 0 to exclude them form grouping.

```
SELECT *, rand() as rand
FROM messages
GROUP BY is_main, CASE WHEN is_main = 0 THEN rand END;
```

And result:

```
+----+---------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| id | is_main | message | status | rand                |
+----+---------+---------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |       0 | testt   |      1 |  0.3822869391946932 |
|  9 |       0 | testt9  |      1 | 0.30222991509570735 |
|  5 |       0 | testt5  |      1 | 0.45369350393646724 |
|  3 |       4 | testt3  |      1 |  0.6502720663792193 |
|  2 |       5 | testt2  |      1 |  0.9594265706459307 |
+----+---------+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

Of course column `rand` is only helper, to solve your problem, it's only used in group.